# Is there an tutorial on how to customize UITableView?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Did actually someone make already a tutorial that shows how to customize an UITableView? I mean a strong customization like for example Tapbots does in Convertbot Settings. Everything is completely customized with own graphics and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a tutorial on some customization here: http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html

Might be what you're after.